# Single query to get predictions from multiple models in a project present in cloud-ml

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I am using the asyncio module in python to query multiple models in a project, in cloud ml to get my predictions. Is there a way to get the predictions from all the models using just one single query.

Say I have an image and want the prediction for this image from three models deployed in google cloud-ml, under one project. Is it possible to write just one query in python which will go to all the models and get the prediction, rather than send three queries, one to each model?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the only way to achieve this is client side, as you are doing, or by deploying an intermediate Cloud Function or similar.